# Определение связей для постов в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Определена таксономия (аналогично тегам), имена в которой совпадают с id поста. Т.е. мы можем получить список постов, на которые ссылается данный пост и список постов, которые ссылаются на данный пост.

Как сделать страницу/отчет/таблицу вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева в столбце id поста, вверху в строке то же самое. Если пост из левого столбца ссылается на пост из верхней строки, то 1, если нет, о 0.

Как это реализовать, чтобы получить на выходе таблицу такой структуры?